# Yii always starts a session when I touch CWebUser

Tags: php, session, yii

I'm developing a RESTful API server which require on some of its API methods a valid session, indicated in the form of a cookie with a session ID.

I'm using Yii v1.1.15 with stock PHP session handler (probably 'files').

Thing is that on every call to CWebUser it creates a session and I don't want this. A session should exists only when I explicitly create it, meaning on login (or register which auto-logins the users). For example, if in a certain API method I check if the user is guest using a construct which involves:

```
Yii::app()->user->isGuest
```

it automatically creates a session since this code is **given** in CWebUser.init().

Now, I'm not in a hurry to change CWebUser (in fact, to change this in the already extending class which altered it slightly, in other aspects) since I'm afraid this will have un-anticipated impact on the system.

Can anyone enlight me on this?

What would you do?

Thanks!

Environment:

---

```
// Yii v1.1.15
// session component configuration: (but believe me, I've tried every 
// combination - its not really related. Check CWebUser.init()...)
'session' => array(
            'class' => 'CHttpSession',
            'autoStart' => false,
            'sessionName' => 'MY_COOKIE_NAME',
            'cookieMode' => 'allow',
            'cookieParams' => ['lifetime' => 1000],
            'gcProbability' => 33,
            'timeout' => 1000,
            'savePath' => '/tmp/',
        ),
// Web User's _allowAutoLogin_ is set on 'false'
```

Answer (score 1):

So you need to check if a user is logged in (This is why you use `isGuest`) but you don't want to use a session?

The method `isGuest` uses a session variable to check if an user is logged in. The session is opened when the `CWebUser` is created. (in the `init` method like you said.) The `isGuest` is part of the `CWebUser` class. If you want to call this method it will always create a session. Unless you overwrite it.

I think you can go 2 ways at this:

1. Open a session, check if a user is logged in (`isGuest`) and then close it only if the user is not logged in. You will need to overwrite the `isGuest` method. Overwrite any other methods to open a session when you need it. (login/register)
2. Let the client send its login data on every request so you dont have to check the session and thus don't have to open it.

In both cases you will need to overwrite the `CWebUser.init()` so it won't open a session whenever the `CWebUser` is created.

Answer (score 0):

So basically this was all a need that came from the following requirement set:

- Yii will be used (also) as a RESTful API server.
- The RESTful server will establish session **only *after* successful login**.
- The above last point implies that there is no session cookie for guest users but rather it exists only for an authenticated user session.

The advantages of the above? mostly the 'free' management of login sessions by the stock PHP session including timeouts, garbage collection etc.

Despite the initial appealing of this design, the drawback overcame the advantages:

- Indeed, isGuest is a property of CWebUser that when tested, already implied a session generated for the request.
- Trying to change the above behavior introduced lots of issues and bugs, and god knows what lurked ahead. In essence, trying to change this behavior on Yii v1.1.x was too problematic as lots of built in features and behaviors (in the abstract meaning...) of Yii based app are implicitly using an established session.

So, I reverted to the following design:

- Yii's session management was reverted to stock - yes please! open a session for everything going on! (just do it well as you normally do).
- The RESTful server sends an explicit session token on successful login calls.
- The client needs to save this token and send it explicitly with every API method that requires an authenticated session.
- Server side saves the session token in the "freely managed" (PHP) session and thus is able to verify on each distinct request that the token for the user with **this** PHP session is indeed his, and is valid.